# OpenApi generator - pass mapping from config file

Tags: c#, .net-core, openapi-generator

I'm using OpenApi generator to generate http client for api tests. I'm using csharp-netcore generator. I want to pass a mapping for models to reuse api models. The problem is that I have lots of classes and when I provide a mapping for all classes using importMapping option I hit command line max length limitation. I need mapping because namespaces are different for all models and I can't put them all into a single namespace to match auto-generated client. Is there a way to pass this configuration from a config file to bypass command line length limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "OpenAPI generator" you mean [Swagger codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) than yes, there is a -c option, where you can pass a path to a json config:

```
swagger-codegen-cli generate
        [(-c <configuration file> | --config <configuration file>)]
```

Whether namespace option can be moved into the config file is apparently language dependant: `config-help -l {lang}`

Should it not be available you could always tweak the source templates or even Java files to handle this value properly.

Comment: I mean https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator but it's a fork of Swagger-codegen so they are mostly compatible. --config option is also working there. thanks!